CrowPi2 Terminal displaying 'Fatal Python error', how do I fix this?
Whenever booting up my crowpi2 laptop, I am faced with a terminal that just displays all of this:
`Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
    Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
    Python path configuration:
    PYTHONHOME = (not set)
    PYTHONPATH = (not set)
    program name = 'python'
    isolated = 0`your text`
    environment = 1
    user site = 1
    safe_path = 0
    import site = 1
    is in build tree = 0
    stdlib dir = '/usr/local/lib/python3.12'
    sys._base_executable =  '/usr/bin/python'
    sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
    sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
    sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
    sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python'
    sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
    sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
    sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python312.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
    ]

Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec for the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0xb6faa010 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>`

So far I have tried reinstalling python, and setting the environment variables. This did not work.
I am thinking about next just reinstalling the OS, but not sure if it will work
Update: Reinstalling the OS fixed the issue

It looks your Python installation lacks the encodings module. You can continue your troubleshooting by looking for its directory within the Python installation by running this: find /usr/local/lib/python3.12 -type d -name encodings.
